# Show $\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}x^{k}e^{-kx}$ converges uniformly in $[0,A]$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, uniform-convergence

Show $\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}x^{k}e^{-kx}$ converges uniformly in $[0,A]$

**Attempt**

There are two ways I've thought about how to approach the problem. One was to show that the series is Cauchy and the other was to apply the Weirstrauss M-Test. In both cases I have to get some sort of bound on my series.

Using the Cauchy approach:

Letting $S_{n}(x) = \sum_{k = 1}^{n} x^{k}e^{-kx}$

$$\|S_{n}(x) - S_{n+m}(x)\|_{\infty} = \sup_{x \in [0,A]} \Bigg|\sum_{k = 1}^{n} x^{k}e^{-kx} - \sum_{k = 1}^{n+m} x^{k}e^{-kx} \Bigg| \leq \sup_{x \in [0,A]} \sum_{k = n}^{n+m} \frac{|x|^{k}}{|e^{x}|^k}$$

So I want to argue in some way that this last expression $\frac{|x|^{k}}{|e^{x}|^k}$ can bound my series. I know for if I put in any $x \in [0,A]$ the ratio of the terms will be less than 1 and from there argue that this is a geometric series. But as can be observed I have an issue at $x = 0$ because the string of inequalities won't be true. It is similar to a fraction of the form $\frac{x^k}{k!}$   which if it was the expression I was working with I could simply compare the terms as  $\frac{x^k}{k!} \leq \frac{A^k}{k!}$ and that would work.

Suggestions or comments on whether either of my approaches is correct?

Comment: The $k$th term is $(xe^{-x})^k$ so if you can find a $C < 1$ such that $|xe^{-x}| < C$ for all $x$ then you can use the Weierstrass $M$-test with $C^k$ as the $k$th term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Try Weierstrass after answering this: What is the maximum of $x^ke^{-kx}$ on $[0,\infty)$?

Comment: I just had to maximize the function by taking the derivative..........So this is maximized at $x = 1$, so now I could use the M - test from here then..... because this is my sequence of bounds.......Even though I'm going to use the M-Test, could I also have shown it is Cauchy with this bound?...I could see it also working.

Comment: Sure, but it would be a little strange as you would just be reproving Weierstrass. Recall that in proving the M test you use $|S_n(x)-S_m(x)| \le \sum_{k=m+1}^n M_k.$ Also note in this problem that we have uniform convergence on $[0,\infty).$

Comment: Your right and in thinking about it, correct me if my thinking is off, but if I were able to show that a series is Cauchy then I would always be able to use the M-Test so in a sense the M-Test  is an "easier" tool to use to establish if a series is uniformly convergent than trying to show it is Cauchy. I can't think of any examples right now, but is there a situation where you can't use the M-Test, but can only show it is Cauchy?

Comment: Yes on your question. For example, on $[1,\infty)$ consider

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\chi_{[n,n+1]}}{x}.$$

This series converges uniformly on $[1,\infty)$ but in this case $M_n = 1/n$ so $\sum M_n = \infty.$

Comment: Great! Thanks...Also reminds me of the plethora of functions available outside of the polynomial looking ones to examine for counterexamples.

Answer (score 2):

It is well known (and easily seen) that $\sum_ky^k$ converges uniformly for $|y|\le a$ for any $a < 1$. Noting that $y = xe^{-x} \le 1/e < 1$ for all $x\in [0,\infty)$ shows that your series converges uniformly on $[0,\infty)$.

Or directly ($x\ge 0$):
$$
\left|\sum_{k=1}^\infty y^k - \sum_{k=1}^ny^k\right| = \left|\frac 1{1-y} - \frac{1-y^{n+1}}{1-y}\right| = \frac{x}{e^x-x}\cdot\left(\frac{x}{e^x}\right)^n\le\frac 1{e-1}\cdot\left(\frac 1e\right)^n.
$$